# multiple subdomains apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, subdomain

I am not much of an admin (nor of an native english speaker, for that matter) and I am struggling with a **simple task**: add a **subdomain** on Apache 2.4. Here are my conf files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.io
    ServerAlias domain.io
    ServerAlias *.domain.io
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/david
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.example.com.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And the second:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.io
    ServerAlias sub.domain.io
    ServerAlias *.sub.domain.io
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ness_pro
    <Directory /var/www/html/ness_pro>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.example.com.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

[**the problem**] Every time I try to access **sub.domain.io** with a browser, I end up on the page related to **domain.io**. I followed the guidelines of apache 2.4 (i.e. edit in sites-available -> a2ensite -> systemctl restart).

[**about my DNS conf**] I redirected **sub.domain.io** to **domain.io** on my DNS provider (Gandi). It points to the right url. I naively thought that apache would analyze the request url to **dispatch between the different VHosts** but it seems that I've been naive. Is there some easy way to fix this (I always found apache url rewriting pretty obscure)?

[**env**] Debian 9 (raspbian) // Apache 2.4

[**edit**] Since everyone is asking. Here is my DNS record

```
@ 10800 IN SOA ns1.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net. 1542647212 10800 3600 604800 10800
@ 10800 IN A 77.193.111.117
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"
blog 10800 IN CNAME blogs.vip.gandi.net.
sub 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
webmail 10800 IN CNAME webmail.gandi.net.
www 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
```

Comment: Hi David, I am not exactly an Apache guru, but I think the order matters here, and I think your `*.domain.io` is matching before the `sub.domain.io`. Why don't you try to set both virtual hosts in the same file, but put the `sub.domain.io` above the `*.domain.io`

Comment: On Debian I am almost sure you can control this order with the filename also, the default is usually `000-default`, you can use 000 for `sub.domain.io` and 001 for `domain.io`, check it out

Comment: I tried to invert the order while putting both on the same conf file but it did not change a thing

Comment: The redirection you are performing, is some Gandi URL redirect or is it a CNAME DNS record?

Comment: not sure what a "CNAME DNS record" is. I would say a Gandi URL redirect: everytime someone is looking for sub.domain.io, he is redirected to the same public ip of domain.io.

Comment: I think you should look for the DNS records to create a CNAME, see [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/62520?hl=en). Also, did you restart apache after changing the order?

Comment: Yes, I did. Like every time I tried something (A LOT OF TIMES)

Comment: @JorgeValentini I checked on Gandi. there is a line in DNS records with **sub.domain.io** type: CNAME. Not sure what it means exactly but since everybody is asking for my DNS conf.... Once again: the redirection works: **sub.domain.io** points to the right url

Comment: Try to change the CNAME to domain.io, avoid that Gandi redirector

Comment: I think that this redirector is for using their own apache simple service like they use it [here](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/faq#i_added_my_vhost_but_it_s_been_3_hours_and_i_still_don_t_see_my_website), however it looks like you are using some kind of VPS that you are configuring from scratch. Makes sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85991/discussion-between-jorge-valentini-and-david-zarebski).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not answer your question, but, I prepared your same scenario, used your same files changing only the DocumentRoot and the order is reversed as I told you in the comments:

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-domain.io.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.io
    ServerAlias sub.domain.io
    ServerAlias *.sub.domain.io
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/serverfault/sub
    <Directory /var/www/html/serverfault/sub>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.example.com.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.io
    ServerAlias domain.io
    ServerAlias *.domain.io
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/serverfault/parent
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.example.com.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Created a test pages in each `DocumentRoot`:

echo "parent" > /var/www/html/serverfault/parent/index.html
echo "sub" > /var/www/html/serverfault/sub/index.html
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/serverfault/ -R

To simulate the DNS I edited the `/etc/hosts` file including:

```
# ...
127.0.0.1   domain.io
127.0.0.1   sub.domain.io
127.0.0.1   www.domain.io
127.0.0.1   www.sub.domain.io
# ...
```

Restarted Apache: `systemctl restart apache2`

And it worked as expected:
[image: Querying the virtualhosts]

Moreover, using the "Tamper Data" plugin for firefox I started manipulating the `Host` header on each request and the response changes in relation to it as expected.

I don't see why yours would not be working. To see if you have any outstanding alerts in the apache service you could use `journalctl -u apache2`

#### DNS

I used the DNS from my domain to be more realistic to your scenario and it worked the same way as using the hosts file, using CNAME or using A records, both of them worked correctly.

As a personal preference, I would say that the A record should be a name for the server, and then CNAMEs for the different host headers, something like (your server for me is 1.1.1.1):

```
webserver01 10800 IN A 1.1.1.1
www 10800 IN CNAME webserver01.domain.io.
sub 10800 IN CNAME webserver01.domain.io.
```

Or in your case you may point the CNAMES to @, where you set the IP:

```
@ 10800 IN SOA ns1.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net. 1542647212 10800 3600 604800 10800
@ 10800 IN A 77.193.111.117

sub 10800 IN CNAME @
www 10800 IN CNAME @
```

I don't know if that syntax is valid, maybe:

```
sub 10800 IN CNAME domain.io.
www 10800 IN CNAME domain.io.
```

(mind the trailing `.`)

A third option would be generating all A records, pointing to the direct IP, maybe just harder to maintain in a bigger environment but equally effective:

```
sub 10800 IN A 1.1.1.1
www 10800 IN A 1.1.1.1
```

One thing for you to consider is that sub is not a subdomain of domain.io as you exposed it, it is only a host for domain.io. You should create a zone to make it a subdomain.

#### Gandi

I am pretty sure that `webredir.vip.gandi.net.` is the responsible for you not getting the expected behavior, if you see the [documentation](http://wiki.gandi.net/en/domains/management/domain-as-website), the redirection type that you are using is the one that says:

> When to use? For traditional web forwarding (ex. to a preexisting website, hosted on another page. This is commonly used to forward a domain to a blog or other free personal page that is already hosted at a given address.)

It looks like a basic redirection for the simplest hosting they offer, if you go to the item 3 in the same page, it says:

> When to use? If your host gives you an IP address for your HTTP server (or if you host it yourself using Gandi's hosting), or tells you to make a particular “A”, “MX”, or “CNAME” (etc.) record in your zone file.

Which, from the information we have, I think is your case, isn't it?

I hope this information and testing helps

Comment: Yeah, it does help. by editing my host, it works -> DNS related, then. I used the "hidden" redirection so I'll switch to the "permanent" and see what's what. I do not dare to edit the DNS record directly, for i) I'm not familiar with the inherent concepts yet ii) and I do not have a static ip (uploading it to gandi's API with a CRON python script every 15 minutes) (the server is, basically, a raspberry pi at my place). I don't wan't to make a mess on my existing config so I'll read first. Many Thanks @Jorge

Comment: Anytime David, let me know if you need further help

Comment: thanks. I'll try your solutions one by one. Every change I make need to to propagate, right?

Comment: In DNS yes, but is usually fast, you can use dig or nslookup to the 8.8.8.8 to verify propagation

Comment: Thanks Jorge, it solved my problem (and I know how to edit DNS records now :-) )

Comment: Amazing man! Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

The first entry contains `ServerAlias *.domain.io`. The address `sub.domain.io` matches `*.domain.io`.

If you want to to use the name `sub.domain.io`, that entry needs to be first, or at least before `*.domain.io`.

Comment: just tried to change the order: it did not change a thing :/

Comment: You mention somthing about "redirecting sub.domain.io to domain.io". What exactly does that mean?

Comment: that means that everytime someone is looking for **sub.domain.io**, he is redirected to the same public ip of **domain.io**. But the urls requests in the http headers are different (I checked)

Comment: You can add `\"%{Host}i\"` to your `Logformat` to log the host the client sends. You may also try to remove the `ServerAlias` that is the same as the `ServerName`. I don't think it's a problem, but it's at least redundant.

Comment: What exact DNS configuration you used? A record or CNAME record? If you added A record only, then it's fine. Question: Does the system behaving the same way if you will remove the second part about sub.domain.io completely? I am asking because it looks like *.domain.io rule is hitting all the time.

Comment: Weird, I just added \"%{Host}i\" to the LogFormat (in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf), refreshed my pages several times and I can't see the hosts in the access.log lines

Comment: @DmitriyKupch I removed the **Server Alias** to check: same issue. "A record or CNAME record"? I am not even sure to understand the difference. All I know is that, based of what I have done, **sub.domain.io** points to my server public ip (and, from what I understand from DNS, that all it needs to do). Requests to both domains point to the right ip, Apache should be able to dispatch based on the *Host* parameter in HTTP headers. Correct me if I am wrong